# get a table from all the server

Tags: sql, sybase

I have 10 databases in a server , is it possible to query for a table in all those databases ?

```
select * from master..sysobjects where name ='table'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below SQL to get all tables for each database. You can edit the SQL in the @SQL parameter to get something else per database if you'd like

```
DECLARE @databaseName VARCHAR(30) 


DECLARE @TABLES TABLE ([Database] VARCHAR(MAX), [Table_Name] VARCHAR(MAX))

DECLARE [DBs] CURSOR FOR  
SELECT name FROM sys.databases


OPEN [DBs]   
FETCH NEXT FROM [DBs] INTO @databaseName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   

        DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT ''' + @databaseName +''' as [Database], Name FROM ['+ @databaseName +'].sys.tables'

        INSERT INTO @TABLES
        EXEC (@SQL)

        FETCH NEXT FROM [DBs] INTO @databaseName  
END   

CLOSE [DBs]   
DEALLOCATE [DBs]  

SELECT * FROM @TABLES
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following steps.

```
Declare @str nvarchar(max)
Select name into #temp from sys.databases
Select  'Select name from '+name+'.sys.tables' AS statements into #temp1  from #temp
Set @str=(Select distinct Stuff((Select ' '+statements from #temp1 for xml path('')),1,1,'') from #temp1)

Exec (@str)
```